Java projects missing after reinstall - (beginner)
I had to reinstall Eclipse because I somehow broke something. But that's not the main issue. Before uninstalling everything, I made a copy of the entire Eclipse workspace folder and stored it in a safe location. After reinstalling Eclipse, I recreated the Eclipse workspace folder and then moved all my saved files into it, along with the .metadata folder and other necessary items. However, when I start Eclipse, it doesn't appear in the package manager.
Even when I try to import it through "General" and every available option, the files don't show up in Eclipse to be added back into my package manager.
I already looked through a lot of different questions here with people who had the similar problem but nothing in their solution helped me

Can you give more concrete details? What was the old Eclipse? What's the new one?

i dont realy know what you mean by old and new eclipse? i am using version 2024-03. but i had problems so i uninstalled it and installed it again.
